# Concatenate select results into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a procedure or select where the rows are going to be converted to lines in an XML file.

It's not hard to pull the data...

```
SELECT '<XMLData'>
SELECT '<Data1>'+data1+'</Data1><Data2>'+data2+'</Data2>' FROM table
SELECT '</XMLData'>
```

But that's giving me 3 result tables.  How do I concatenate them into 1?

Comment: Edit your question and show what you want in the end.  Do you want one result set or one XML value?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT '<XMLData>' as xmlResult
UNION ALL
SELECT '<Data1>'+data1+'</Data1><Data2>'+data2+'</Data2>' FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT '</XMLData>'
```

Comment: Is this guaranteed to preserve order?  I don't want a situation where `</XMLData>` appears before `<XMLData>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want just one row, you could concatenate them.  Casting it as XML will preserve the XML structure in the field.

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT('<XMLData>', 
                   '<Data1>'+data1+'</Data1><Data2>'+data2+'</Data2>', 
                   '</XMLData>') as XML) as 'Result 
FROM table
```